# Using NSURLConnection to post data to PHP script

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, post, nsurlconnection

I'm completely new to Objective-C and XCode. I created a single-view application for an iPhone. There are 3 textboxes and a button in the view. I need to have the button POST data to a PHP script, and the data is coming from the 3 textboxes. I have been told to use `NSURLConnection`, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) using it in this way:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:someUrl];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"..." forKey:@"user"];
[request setPostValue:@"..." forKey:@"password"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsyncrhonous];
```

and in php called in `someUrl` you get variable ( EXAMPLE )

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Is more simple using `ASIHTTPRequest` instead `NSURLConnection`

Comment: How would I call that using a button? And how would I set the values of User and Password to be from textboxes?

Comment: First, you have to create in .h of your viewcontroller an ibaction in this way: -(IBAction)sendPost; in .m implement it -(IBAction)sendPost{ some code }, and in .xib click on button and link it to the ibaction. now when you click button, the method sendPost is called. to get text from uitextfield is simple. just save in NSString the value in this way: NSString *text1 = self.textfield1.text etc..; so in sendPost save the text from NSString and use my code before :)